# Find one or more unique words in any cell and provide a specific return value for each in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry in advance if this is really basic for you all. I have been searching on the web and can't find the answer.

I'm trying to find one or more unique words in any cell and provide a specific return value for each in excel. Some cells have multiple words in them. Others have just one. For example I want word1 to give a value in column A of the value "1". I want word2 to give a value in column A of "0". If both words are found together I need it to add both values together to make a single value. So like if word3 ended up being a value of 2.9 and word1 was also in the same cell, I would want them added making it a value of 3.9 in column A.

Here's what I have so far:

=IF(XOR(E2="word1", E2="word2"), 1,0)

I've also tried:
=IF(IF(E2="word1", 1, 0)+(E2="word2", 1,0)
=IF(IF(E2="word1", 1, 0) E2="word2", 1,0) 
=IF(AND(E2="word1", E2="word2"), 1,0)
=IF(OR(E2="word1", E2="word2"), 1,0)

All I am getting is a return value for one of the words, or none on my current formula. But the other formulas I tried aren't valid formulas. So I'm unsure where to go. I thought for sure that the first one I tried would have worked...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you assign a value to each word eg

```
Word1 = 1
Word2 = 2
Word3 = 2.5
```

So you want to see something like this:

[image]

Use this formula (if the values are pasted to column K row 2).  NB this is an array formula so you must enter it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND("Word1", K2)>0, 1, 0), 0), IFERROR(IF(FIND("Word2", K2)>0, 2, 0), 0), IFERROR(IF(FIND("Word3", K2)>0, 2.5, 0), 0))
```